# Have chrome sync not use Youtube's servers to login

Tags: google-chrome, sync

I am trying to use Google Chrome Portable to sync my browsing history and whatnot on a public network. They block bandwidth-heavy websites, like youtube and netfix. When I try to login, I get this page:

[image]

Here's some more information:

- I can't access any youtube page at all, even if it's an iFramed video or something
- Usually `https://` bypasses this however it doesn't always
- It's because of the network block

I want to know how I force chrome to use a non-youtube.com url to sync accounts (like with gmail, which uses `accounts.google.com`)

Comment: Ok, you say the network you're on blocks YouTube.com, and then you show us a picture showing that, yes, it appears they are blocking it.  I'm confused as to what your question is?   What have you attempted already?  Have you cleared your cache? Does it work if you clear you history and try to sync a blank one?  It may just not be possible since Youtube is owned by Google, and Google has all the accounts tied together, so it probably logs into multiple Google sites to check/save/sync your history.  Perhaps, especially if you have YouTube entries in your history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain why you are trying to sync your browsing history? Does youtube.com load? your picture that you posted shows https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/ and then your session ID data.

Did you just try to load a bookmark and you got this error OR were you able to go to youtube.com but once you click to login that you get this error.

## THIS DOES MAKE A DIFFERENCE

Several things could be occurring.

1. Most likely the hosts file is blocking the sites you want to visit. To bypass this temporarily edit as administrator the HOSTS file located in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\ and find the entries and add a # at the beginning of each specific entry. When you are done on that computer then remove your # additions and re-save the file.

## IT'S IMPORTANT THAT YOU DO THIS

Because if you don't and I was their administrator and noticed traffic on my network like youtube then that's the first thing I would check if I deployed a custom hosts file. If I see that someone edited it then I'd tighten down security and revoke local access to the file. for more info on the hosts file check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

2.Their DNS could have a record manually re-routing the domain names to a bad IP address. From DOS ping google.com, netflix.com, youtube.com as well as accounts.youtube.com. You could also try using the IP address that is returned from the ping in the browser and see if they are just blocking the actual names and not the servers where they reside. You can also change your DNS server IP's to a free public one: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/free-public-dns-servers.htm

## IF YOU CHANGE DNS IP'S write them down first and restore them before you leave otherwise it might only work once.

3.The firewall has a rule blocking the site and isn't setup to show a "this site has been blocked and your IP address and logon credentials have been sent to the administrator" notification. If the firewall is blocking it then the only possible circumvention would to trying proxies or VPN's. You may have luck with a paid proxy or VPN service VS free since they could be blocking the free sites.

4.If you are unable to bypass this using the first three methods then see if your existing home router supports connecting to your home router via a VPN connection. If not then see if your hardware is supported using a third party firmware like DD-WRT, tomato, or gargoyle. If not then purchase a new router that is supported or has VPN support from the manufacturer. You DO NOT WANT TO BUILD A SPLIT TUNNEL since this will only send traffic through the VPN that is on your home's physical network.

5.Lastly you could build your own DNS tunnel if the admin isn't blocking it. Check out: http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2008-11/02-dns_tunneling_made_simple

This also usually works at places that advertise WiFi and when you get there say it's an additional charge, but when places state that it's not free before going there you should just opt to pay or take your business elsewhere.

Please answer my questions and let me know what you find out based on what I provided as answers.

Comment: It's Trustwave filter. Usually it shows an `ACCESS DENIED` page (yes, it is in all caps) but occasionally doesn't.

Comment: Can you connect via VPN out or use a proxy?

Comment: Yes however I don't want to download and install a proxy every time I download this to a new computer.

Comment: You don't install a proxy, in internet explorer its under tools > Internet Options > Connections[tab] > LAN Settings[button]. check the button for use a proxy server for your LAN and put in the settings for the proxy server that you will pivot your traffic off of. Also Google "portable Apps" it sounds like you want something like a portable VPN but the only one I know of is paid software and not free, check out http://www.portablevpn.nl/taal_UK/index.htm